# Elasticsearch char_filter replace any character with whitespace?

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I'm using elasticsearch for my Ruby on Rails application. I want to use [char_filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/mapping-charfilter.html) to replace some characters with whitepace.

In tutorial of elasticsearch it says something like:

```
"mappings" : ["ph=>f", "qu=>q"]
```

I've tried the following:

```
"mappings" : ["ph=>\s", "qu=>\s"]
```

However it does not seem to work. Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use \uXXXX notation for spaces:

```
"mappings" : ["ph=>\s", "qu=>\\u0020"]
```