# How to match different instances of the same query in Elasticsearch?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

Example 1:
My query term is "abcd".

My query structure is like this:

```
    query: {
       query_string: {
          query: "abc",
          fields: ["field1", "field2", "field3"]
       }
    },
    size: 50,
    "highlight": {
    "fields": {
        "field1": {},
        "field2": {},
        "field3": {}
    }
```

It matches the following instances:

```
abc abcs abc_def_ghi
```

But it does not match def_abc or def_abc_ghi.
Basically instances where abc is in the middle of a string.

Example 2:
In the same example above, if my query is abc_def

It does not match abc_def_ghi, although abc_def is present.

I have tried prefix_phrase and it solves scenario 2 but misses out on example 1's problems.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

for these usages you should use [wildcard in query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_wildcards) or [regular expression](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_regular_expressions)

if you are using term query you can utilize [wildcard term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) or [regexp query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

- As name suggests `phase_prefix` is like poor mans autocomplete it searches for fields which starts with given phrase in your case  `abc`,`abcs`,`abc_def_ghi`. as your field doesn't start with `abc` in case of `def_abc`,`def_abc_ghi` it won't work with phrase prefix.
- Try using [character filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-charfilters.html) specifically [Pattern Replace Character Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html) to replace `_` with (space) from your field while [analyzing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) your field. check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501517/elasticsearch-char-filter-replace-any-character-with-whitespace) . so your token would result in  `[def,abc,ghi]` instead of single token like `[def_abc_ghi]`. then you can search it using [cross_field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_cross_fields_queries.html) on analyzed field which should satisfy all of your mentioned cases.